# resizing view after iAd shows up

Tags: swift, frame, iad

so am having problems resizing the view after the iAd shows up, its blocking bottom part of the view. i can start off by already making space for the banner but this doesn't look so good, looks like an empty white space. i would like to update the view based on the iAd when it shows up and when it disappears, both the views are added programmatically. here is some code

```
 func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.bannerView1.hidden = false
    print("BANNERVIEWSHOWN")     
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.bannerView1.hidden = true
    print("BANNERVIEWHIDDEN")


}
```

in viewdidload()

```
    bannerView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerView1.delegate = self
    bannerView1.hidden = true





    self.pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)


    pageMenu!.delegate = self



    self.view.addSubview(self.pageMenu!.view)

     self.view.addSubview(bannerView1)



    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView": bannerView1]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

how would i make it so that it grew and shrunk depending on the iAd?
i know i could have played around with the height constraint if it was made using the interface builder but its not...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it to do the resize using the constraints:

```
    // Setup our BannerView
    bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,bannerView.frame.width,bannerView.frame.height)
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true

    view.addSubview(bannerView)

    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView": bannerView]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[bannerView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```